# Not able to compile code containing generics and inner classes

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inner-classes

I am trying to implement Singly Linked List. I am not able to compile the following code. I have removed lot of unnecessary code which is not relevant for this question from the below snippet:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T>
{
    public SinglyLinkedList()
    {
    }

    private SinglyNode<T> _head = null;

    private class SinglyNode<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public SinglyNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    }

    private class Enumerator<T>
    {
        public Enumerator(SinglyLinkedList<T> list)
        {
            _list = list; //#1
            _head = list._head; //#2
        }

        private SinglyLinkedList<T> _list = null;
        private SinglyNode<T> _head = null;
    }
}
```

The statement marked #2 is failing with the error - `Cannot implicitly convert type 'SinglyLinkedList<T>.SinglyNode<T>' to 'SinglyLinkedList<T>.SinglyNode<T> Program.cs`

The statement marked #1 is semantically similar to #2 and it is compiling. What is stopping the program to compile? Are there any genercis + inner classes related rules that are causing the above code to not compile?

Please make a note that the above code snippet is part of my learning by reinventing the wheel and is not a production code.

Comment: Drop the `<T>` in `SinglyNode<T>` and `Enumerator<T>`

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that C# allows this kind of generic parameter shadowing.

Comment: @CodesInChaos it does, however, tell you that it is probably a mistake: the code in the question has two of: "warning CS0693: Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'SinglyLinkedList<T>'"

Comment: @Anand - it is **always** worth reading the compiler warnings ^^^

Comment: @MarcGravell - Yes Marc. I did not focused on warnings because there were errors. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner classes each declare their own **completely different** `T`.

Just remove the `T` from the inner classes and all will be well:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T>
{
    public SinglyLinkedList()
    {
    }

    private SinglyNode _head = null;

    private class SinglyNode
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public SinglyNode Next { get; set; }
    }

    private class Enumerator
    {
        public Enumerator(SinglyLinkedList<T> list)
        {
            _list = list; //#1
            _head = list._head; //#2
        }

        private SinglyLinkedList<T> _list = null;
        private SinglyNode _head = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove it also on `public SinglyNode<T> Next { get; set; }`

Comment: I saw that in the C# warnings :)

Comment: @trippino fixed; now compiles

Comment: @MarcGravell - I will mark your response as answer. Would it be possible for you to put the rule in a plain English and provide some more explanation? That will help me and other developers like me to get the hold of the actual rule.

Comment: @AnandPatel the "rule" there is simply: nested classes automatically inherit any generic type parameters from their parent types; so `SinglyNode` is ***already*** generic - but via the parent. It is `SinglyLinkedList<T>.SinglyNode`; a `SinglyLinkedList<int>.SinglyNode` is a different type to a `SinglyLinkedList<string>.SinglyNode`

Comment: @MarcGravell: +1. I was looking for that kind of explanation.